¿Como puedo validar desde mi API que un cliente fue logueado correctamente con Azure?
Estoy trabajando en un sistema que se divide en dos, un frontend en Angular y un backend en Node.
El problema es que la autenticación del usuario se realiza por AzureAD y una vez inicia sesión obtengo el token de acceso. Sin embargo, no conozco cual es el siguiente paso.
¿Debo mandar este token de acceso para que mi API valide su autenticidad? Si ese es el caso, ¿Cómo lo hago?
Mi aplicación de Angular ya se encuentra registrada en Azure, y en mi API intenté validar el token con JWT, utilizó las llaves ligadas a mi TENANTID, el aud y el issuer y el cliente ID. Pero los resultados eran "Invalid Signature".
Mis sospechas son que se tratan por un tema de scopes, ya que no tengo mi API registrada en Azure y utilizó los scopes por defecto.
También he realizado pruebas siguiendo el tutorial o ejemplo de aquí:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-javascript-react-tutorial/tree/main/3-Authorization-II/1-call-api
Pero veo que registran las dos y utilizan passport con los scopes asignados en la API de Node. Lo que me deja una última pregunta:
¿Es necesario registrar las dos aplicaciones (front y back) si quiero realizar validaciones desde mi API?

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
